# PHP validation - input type"text" value must be one specific word

Tags: php, validation

I am very sorry if this seems like a "Sigh, another one of those~" questions, but I've looked far and wide, yet none of the things seemed to suit my needs. I've looked at games like hangman, but they did it letter for letter and I couldn't figure out what to do with the code. (incompetence on my side, I admit. My knowledge is quite limited)

I then decided to look at quizzes, but they seemed to only deal with radio buttons. I've tried to edit scripts so that they had input type text boxes, but that seemed to lead to a lot more problems, seeing as I turned the question from multiple choice to open answer.

All I really want, is a basic setup like this:

Question
Input box
Button (submit, I think?)

Nothing fancy aesthetically-wise, just those three things.

Summary: How do I get my code to check if the answer they've given to the question is, for example, banana? And how do I get the button to -only- work if the word is indeed banana?

I'm very lost after several days of searching now. Many thanks for any effort you guys put into this, it'd mean a lot to me.

Comment: Javascript `onkeyup` function - test whether the value is "banana" then enable the button. Otherwise, disable the button.

Comment: Is it a PHP or a Javascript question? What is your current code?

Comment: You want server side validation for that??

Comment: You'd want to validate this on the server side, and that is pretty easy - `if (strtolower(trim($_POST['fieldname'])) == 'banana') { /* right */ } else { ?* wrong */ }`. Basically the same in JS as well.

Comment: Where is your code?? What you have tried?

Comment: @DaveRandom You can't enable/disable a button based on user-input in "real-time" using PHP. "Real-time" updating is what OP is trying to do, I think.

Comment: If you want to do it in real time, you'll need to use AJAX for this.  You can mix javascript and php together to hide the answer away from your source code.

Comment: @Matt OK fair comment - but it would *still* need validating server side to prevent spoofing.

Comment: @DaveRandom I agree. Just to be safe, a server-side validation would be optimal.

Comment: @TonyMancini you don't need AJAX for this. There's no need to submit anything to the server before the user hits `submit`. All you need is DHTML via javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @Matt, to clarify, AJAX is only needed if he wants to hide his answer away from his source code.  Otherwise, a simple javascript function that runs `onkeyup` should do the trick.

Comment: @TonyMancini clarification accepted. +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

basically you would change the submit button to a normal button, and run a javascript function to check if the value is correct before submitting the form. Something like:

```
<script>
    function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('check_value').value == 'banana') {
            document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
        }
        else {
            alert("Incorrect value.");
        }
    }
</script>
<form id='myForm' method='POST' action='process.php'>
    <input type='text' id='check_value' />
    <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='validate();' />
</form>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh no, how does this work.. I'm sorry, just a moment while I try to figure this out.

Comment: @ralfe, Protip: you might want to let the browser know which language the `script` is written in.

Comment: Right! this does exactly what I want to do. I'm sorry for the confuion up above, I wanted to make a comment in general then completely failed that and panicked.

Comment: @Matt this is only optional, the default script language for a long time has been javascript and as such using `type="text/javascript"` is uneeded.

Comment: @Benchkey if my answer was correct and solved your problem, please mark it as correct by using the tock to the left of the answer.

Answer (score -2):

This is some basic client-side scripting using javascript.

Using the `onkeyup` event, we can test the value of what the user is typing in the text box, compare it to the "correct" value and enable/disable our submit button based on that evaluation.

```
<div id="question">How do you spell "banana"?</div><br />
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" disabled="true" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $("#answer").on('keyup', function() { 
        if ($(this).val() == "banana") {
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", "true");
        }
    });
</script>
```

As others have pointed out, you'll want to verify the input on the server-side, just in case the user is a jerk and has disabled javascript.

```
<?php

    if ($_POST['answer'] == "banana") {
        // we're OK, do something
    } else {
        // return to the form and let the user know he's a cheater!
    }
```

Comment: I agree that you should probably use javascript, but you MUST validate server side too to avoid tampering on the front end.

Comment: Then I just disable Javascript and type rubbish in the field and submit the form :-)

Comment: @Jocelyn that isn't a reason to avoid using javascript.  It provides a great way of providing user feedback to any normal user.  However as I pointed out you just need that extra level of check on the server side just to make sure.

Comment: @Jocelyn the only way to do this is via `javascript`. If the user wants to be a jerk, that's his problem.

Comment: @Jon: I was trying to point the fact that the Javascript code, while useful, won't be enough to ensure real form validation.

Comment: Matt, whether we like it or not there will always be jerks that try and break our code, therefore yes, using javascript is part of the solution but you must do more than this to protect yourself against said "jerks".

Comment: I would actually go as far as to make the button enabled as default, disable it with javascript.  The javascript should be a complement but should not be a necessity.  Having an enabled button by default means those who have javascript disabled can also use the website and rely on the server side validation.

Comment: @JonTaylor that's 100% accurate, but I highly doubt that whatever OP is doing will require that level of security.

Comment: @JonTaylor if you don't have javascript enabled, you're failing at the internet. I wouldn't code in a way that placates less than 1% of users.

Comment: @JonTaylor call me elitist, call me ridiculous, call me whatever. The fact of the matter is that the most popular sites out there (facebook, google, myspace [HA! can you imagine?]) rely on javascript being enabled for a fully immersive UX. Do you disagree with this fact?

Comment: I don't disagree, but all fallback and are useable without it.  They all face the fact that not all users have javascript enabled, and so should we.  Don't just assume people must be backwards to not have javascript enabled.

Comment: @JonTaylor it's not an assumption, it's a fact. :-)

Comment: @Matt well I have javascript disabled on one of my tablets since it runs significantly faster, this is not backwards, this is just plain common sense since the browsing I do on it doesn't need it and since I know that good programmers make sure they always provide a fallback to those who don't have it enabled.  You use examples of other websites such as facebook, google etc all of which do the one thing you say you shouldnt bother with.  I think you sir are the one who is backwards.